# Python Error: __init__() takes at least 5 arguments (4 given)

Tags: python, class

So I have searched every one of these questions but I didn't find anything helping me.

I'm still relatively new to Python and I have this class for a simple dialogue box displaying some text:

```
class DialogueBox(object):
    def __init__(self, text, font, size, wh, pos="center", padding=20):
        self.text = text
        self.font = font
        self.size = size
        self.width = wh[0]
        self.height = wh[1]

        self.image = pygame.image.load("img/dialogue_box_background.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (self.width, self.height))

        if pos == "center":
            self.pos[0] = screensize[0] - (self.width / 2)
            self.pos[1] = screensize[1] - (self.height / 2)
        else:
            self.pos = pos

        self.textpos = tuple(self.pos[0] + (padding / 2), self.pos[1] + (padding / 2))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.pos[0], self.pos[1], self.width, self.height)

        self.textfont = pygame.font.Font(font,size)
        self.textsurf = self.textfont.render(text, 1, (255,255,255))

        if self.textsurf.get_width() > (width - padding):
            self.mode = "long"
        else:
            self.mode = "short"

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.pos)
        if self.mode == "short":
            textfunc(self.text, self.font, (self.textpos[0] + (self.width / 2), self.textpos[1] + (self.height / 2), (255,255,255)))
        else:
            blit_text(screen, self.text, self.textpos, self.textfont, pygame.Color("white"))
```

Anyway, I then do

```
opts_rsto_box = DialogueBox(curlang["cfdial"][0],genfont,(100,100))
```

and get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\Programmieren\SpaceStrategieGame\p.py", line 191, in <module>
        update_rects()
    File "D:\Programmieren\SpaceStrategieGame\p.py", line 182, in update_rects
        opts_rsto_box = DialogueBox(curlang["cfdial"][0],genfont,(100,100))
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 5 arguments (4 given)
```

which is pretty weird because the class has only 4 required arguments.

Really sorry if this is a stupid question but I don't understand why I get this error.

**EDIT**: I see now that I am in fact stupid and oversaw that I didn't pass enough arguments, I was sure I did. Thanks for your answers and sorry for wasting your time like this.

Comment: you are only passing 3 arguments and it needs at least one more

Comment: As @depperm said you are only passing 3 arguments, it's written 4 arguments because `self` is implicitly passed.

Comment: Oh god, I am so stupid. I could've sworn I checked it enough. Thanks for your answers, works now.

Comment: could you also rename your question to __init__() takes at least 5 arguments (4 given)

Answer (score 3):

You are only passing it three arguments. (100, 100) is a tuple (one argument instead of two).

Hannu

Answer (score 2):

```
opts_rsto_box = DialogueBox(curlang["cfdial"][0],genfont,(100,100))
```

`(100,100)` is a tuple, which is just one argument, not two different ones.

Answer (score 1):

The fifth argument is `self` itself which is passed automatically. You are not passing the `wh` argument in the constructor. It might be that the tuple (100,100), which acts as one argument, should be split into two independent ones to comply with the constructor signature.